# How to use external scss or css file with material UI? (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styles

I am facing problem with external css files on my react project. I am using material UI components. In the react components folder I created css file for each components but they are not loading when i hard reload the site.

I wanted to use external css rather than styled components or material ui style syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Just import the css / scss file in your component and make sure you've added the classes for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking a more generic option you can import your style.css file in your main App.jsx (if you call it "App.jsx") file. Then you just use the `className` and will have access to your css.

**App.jsx file**

```
import './style.css'; // Your path to your style.css    

function App() {
  return (
    <div>React app</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```